# Java reAdd items that have been removed from JComboBox

Tags: java

What i'm trying to do is whenever i press the "Remove" Button it will remove the item that i have selected in the JComboBox. So once i have removed all the items, I have another button called "Reset" where all the items that have been removed will be inside the JComboBox again and is it possible to have a restore method instead of having to reAdd each model again cause my actual program has lots of models

This is what i have tried but it doesnt work any suggestions how can this be done?

```
public class Testing{

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton remove,reset;
    JComboBox box;
    final DefaultComboBoxModel items = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]
    {
        "-","Database System","Computer Fundamentals",
        "Computer Maths","Internet Web Tech","Tertiary English 1"                              
    });

    public void display()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        box = new JComboBox();
        box.setModel(items);
        remove = new JButton("Remove");
        reset = new JButton("Reset");

        remove.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)->{   
        box.removeItem(box.getSelectedItem());
        });

        reset.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)->{    
        System.out.println("Reset");
        box.setModel(items);
        box.revalidate();
        box.repaint();

        });

        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
        panel.add(box);
        panel.add(remove);
        panel.add(reset);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TestingProgram te = new TestingProgram();
        te.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: add a print statement inside the reset actionlistener to make sure it's actually firing

Comment: yes i added and it is firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Here is the new code:

```
 public class Test{

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton remove,reset;
    JComboBox box;
    final DefaultComboBoxModel items = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]
    {
        "-","Database System","Computer Fundamentals",
        "Computer Maths","Internet Web Tech","Tertiary English 1"                              
    });
    public DefaultComboBoxModel getClone(DefaultComboBoxModel items) {
        DefaultComboBoxModel clone = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        for(int i = 0;i<items.getSize();i++) {
            clone.addElement(items.getElementAt(i));
        }
        return clone;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        box = new JComboBox();
        box.setModel(getClone(items));
        remove = new JButton("Remove");
        reset = new JButton("Reset");

        remove.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)->{   
        box.removeItem(box.getSelectedItem());
        });

        reset.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)->{    


        box.setModel(getClone(items));


        });

        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
        panel.add(box);
        panel.add(remove);
        panel.add(reset);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Test te = new Test();
        te.display();
    }
 }
```

The problem was that you were using the same `DefaultComboBoxModel`, and every time you removed an item from the `JComboBox`, it actually removed it from your `DefaultComboBoxModel` item. That means that when you reset the model, the stuff you removed had also been removed from your `DefaultComboBoxModel`, and it didn't do anything

This new code makes a clone of your `DefaultComboBoxModel` and adds that, so when you remove stuff from it, it doesn't effect the `final` one

Comment: it works perfectly thanks alot Jamal ill mark this as solved

Comment: @dexter no problem :)